# How to use jQuery to append data to the correct div?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying understand jQuery and have gotten myself so confused over how to 
append some new html data into the correct div depending on which button was clicked. I would really appreciate some pointers. I've made a fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/bfmsmouu/3/)

I want to append the new_data to the list of names depending on which button was clicked. So if button_1 is pressed the new_name is appended to the spans in `#container_1` and if button_2 is pressed the data is appended to the spans in `#container_2`.

I realise I am having trouble figuring out which button was pressed, how to locate the div where I want to place the new data and how to append it. I've been so overloaded with different ways of doing it I can't think straight,

html

```
<button class="button" id="button_1">press</button>
<div class="some_div" id="div_1">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start" id="container_1">

        <span>name_1</span>
        <span>name_2</span>
        <span>name_3</span>

    </div>
</div>

<button class="button" id="button_2">press</button>
<div class="some_div" id="div_2">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start" id="container_2">

        <span>name_4</span>
        <span>name_5</span>
        <span>name_6</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button_1").click(function() { //Find which button was clicked
        var find_div=$(".button").attr("id"); //Trying to find the div 
        $(find_div).append.html("<span>new_name</span>"); // Append the data to the div
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data` attribute to detect which div should be updated.

Also, I cleaned your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() { //Find which button was clicked
        var which_id = $(this).data('id');
        $("#container_" + which_id).append("<span>new_name</span>"); // Append the data to the div
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="button_1" data-id="1">press</button>
<div class="some_div" id="div_1">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start" id="container_1">

        <span>name_1</span>
        <span>name_2</span>
        <span>name_3</span>

    </div>
</div>

<button class="button" id="button_2" data-id="2">press</button>
<div class="some_div" id="div_2">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start" id="container_2">

        <span>name_4</span>
        <span>name_5</span>
        <span>name_6</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great., really clear and just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @JulianJ. I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You're only listening for clicks of `button_1`, so let's change that to accept click events for *all* buttons of class "button".
2. We can use `$(this)` to get the clicked button, and `.next("div")` to get the next `<div>`. We'll store this as `$nextDiv`.
3. We can then use `$nextDiv.append()` to append HTML to `find_div`.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var $nextDiv = $(this).next("div"); //Find the next div 
        $nextDiv.append("<span>new_name</span>"); // Append the data to the div 
    });
});
```

For your purpose, this should work. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/aqrkxpzk/1/) is an example.

(If you want the button id # to match the div id #, see the other answers which have supplied this functionality for you. My example will automatically grab the `<div>` after the clicked button.)

Comment: Nicely explained, great lesson. Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't .next find the first div after the button?

Comment: It does, or at least if will if implemented correctly. I've included an example in my answer that you can take a look at where it shows the functionality working as intended. If you're trying to add it to the same div as the other spans, you can change `$nextDiv` to this instead: `var $nextDiv = $(this).next("div").children("div").first();`

Answer (score 2):

Heres a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Darin_Cardin/hf6qLycv/4/

```
<button class="button" id="button_1" data='container_1'>press</button>
<div class="some_div" id="div_1">
<div class="d-flex align-items-start" id="container_1">

  <span>name_1</span>
  <span>name_2</span>
  <span>name_3</span>

</div>
</div>
<button class="button" id="button_2" data='container_2'>press</button>
<div class="some_div" id="div_2">
<div class="d-flex align-items-start" id="container_2">

<span>name_4</span>
<span>name_5</span>
<span>name_6</span>

</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() { //Find which button was clicked
        var data = $(this).attr("data"); //Trying to find the div 
       var find_div = $('#' + data);   
        $(find_div).append("<span>new_name </span>"); 
    });
});
```